# Update specific field in database object | Axios, Redux forms

Tags: javascript, server, put, redux-form, axios

I have  an object called `item`:

And I also have a PUT request that sould be able to change some of the values inside of `item`. Some values are inside of objects and others aren't. An example is that I need to be able to change the values inside of the `settings` obj. Currently my PUT request looks like this:

```
export function updateSettings(id, item) {
  return dispatch => {
    axios
      .put(`${settings.hostname}/cookie/${id}`, item)
      .then(res => {
        dispatch({
          type: 'COOKIES_UPDATED',
          payload: {
            item
          }
        })
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }
}
```

And when logging `res.data` I'm only getting this:
`_id: "598960d891202556389cxd"`

Here's how the backend proccess PUT requests:

```
r.put('/cookies' + '/:id', async (ctx, next) => {
  console.log(key)
  await ctx.db
    .replaceOne({ _id: objectId(ctx.params.id) }, ctx.request.body)

  ctx.body = { _id: ctx.params.id }
  console.log(ctx.request.body)
})
```

I am using Redux form to submit my input fields and my `onSubmit` looks like this:

```
onSubmit={handleSubmit(props => {
  // props is the updated form values
  onSubmit(id, props)
})}
```

This sends of the new values to server and updates the db, but it also messes with the structure of my `item` object. Some fields are getting removed, so I got the tip to use `diff`.`Diff`'s (https://github.com/srcagency/object-diff) purpose is to ONLY send if the changes to the server, but in my case, it doesen't update anything. `Item` looks exacly the same.

So there is my problem, I don't know how to update the specific field in my `item` object. I can send more code if needed.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: why did you just send the axios(ajax) code and not your server update file? and show us how item variable look like.

Comment: @RahmatAligos I'm sorry, I will add those two.

Comment: I've updated sir @RahmatAligos

Comment: Did you want to update item.settings object? make sure `.put(`${settings.hostname}/locks/${id}`, item)` is defined eg: `var item = {settingName: 'Seting Name'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
router.route('/cookies/:id')
.put(function(req, res) {

    Items.findById(req.params.id, function(err, item) {

        if (err)
            res.send(err);

        // if you want update all settings object
        item.settings = req.body;
        // if something on settings field, item.settings.field1 = req.body.field1
        item.save(function(err) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json({ message: 'Your item updated!' });
        });

    });
});
```